# Adding default tag ('asp-for') in custom tag helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, helper, tag-helpers

Please help me to add default tag ('asp-for') in custom tag helper for checkboxlist.
I want to use the tag like default.

Tag helper:

```
 [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-checklistbox, asp-modelname")]
public class CheckListBoxTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-checklistbox")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-modelname")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {


        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var selected = item.Selected ? @"checked=""checked""" : "";
            var disabled = item.Disabled ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "";

            var html = $@"<label><input type=""checkbox"" {selected} {disabled} id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Selected"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Selected"" value=""true"" /> {item.Text}</label>";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Value"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Value"" value=""{item.Value}"">";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Text"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Text"" value=""{item.Text}"">";

            output.Content.AppendHtml(html);

            i++;
        }

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "th-chklstbx");
    }

}
```

View:

```
 <div asp-checklistbox="workTypeList" asp-modelname="workTypeId" asp-for="workTypeId"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic `asp-for` implementation from standard [helpers](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers).

Mark your tag helper with [HtmlTargetElement("mychecklistbox", Attributes = "asp-for")] and add to your `CheckListBoxTagHelper` class this property:

```
/// <summary>
/// An expression to be evaluated against the current model.
/// </summary>
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

And use this `For` property for output `HTML` you need to access the `Model` detail like `Name`. See standard helpers which use it - e.g. [`LabelTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs) or others.

Answer (score 0):

Should I change that line:

```
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {


        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var selected = item.Selected ? @"checked=""checked""" : "";
            var disabled = item.Disabled ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "";

            var html = $@"<label><input type=""checkbox"" {selected} {disabled} id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Selected"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Selected"" value=""true"" /> {item.Text}</label>";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Value"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Value"" value=""{item.Value}"">";
            html += $@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{i}__Text"" name=""{ModelName}[{i}].Text"" value=""{item.Text}"">";

            output.Content.AppendHtml(html);

            i++;
        }

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "th-chklstbx");
    }
```